# SQL Server Management Studio: Policy - ExecuteSql throws error if the statement string contains an empty field

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2019, for-xml-path, string-agg

I want a SQL Server Management Policy to check the values in a delimited list returned by FOR XML. The problem is that "FOR XML ('')" will throw a SQL error.

I may not post screenshots or site-specific details so I will demonstrate the error using a simple example:

1. In SQL Server Management Studio, open Object Explorer, expand Management, expand Policy Management, expand Policies to see the existing policies.
2. Right click Policies and choose New Policy...
3. Give it a name: List Databases
4. Click Check Condition and then New Condition
5. Name the condition: List Databases
6. Click the ellipsis button to the right of the Expression Field
7. Type in this statement:

   ```
   ExecuteSql('String','SELECT name + '', '' FROM sys.databases FOR XML PATH')
   ```
8. Click OK
9. In the Value field, enter the database names separated by a comma and space: 'master, tempdb, model, msdb, database1, database2, '
10. Operator is '='
11. Click OK
12. Click OK

Now right-click and evaluate the policy. It's not true because the XML has delimiters:

```
'<row>master, </row><row>tempdb, </row><row>model, </row><row>msdb, </row><row>database1, </row><row>database2, </row>'
```

I want to get rid of the `</row><row>` to reduce the string length to a manageable length. I get the error when I modify the query string to this:

```
ExecuteSql('String','SELECT name + '', '' FROM sys.databases FOR XML PATH('''')')
```

The error is

> Exception encountered while executing policy 'List Databases'. Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')'. Incorrect syntax near ')'. Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 105)

Why does it detect a quotation mark mismatch?

For the short lists, I added the `</row><row>` delimiters to the comparison string. However, I have a long list that is too long and truncates the return string with delimiters.

This is on SQL Server 2019

Comment: I don't know whether this will solve your problem and let you do what you are trying to do w.r.t. SQL Management Policies but as you are on 2019 you should use `string_agg` to get a delimited list anyway

Comment: Thank you. string_agg works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FOR XML PATH('')` to get text without XML tags.

Note the extra use of a subquery and `, TYPE).value` to de-escape the XML.

```
ExecuteSql('String','SELECT (SELECT name + '', '' FROM sys.databases FOR XML PATH(''''), TYPE).value(''text()[1]'')')
```

But since you are on SQL Server 2019, you can just use `STRING_AGG`

```
ExecuteSql('String','SELECT STRING_AGG(name, '', '') FROM sys.databases')
```

Note that this version does not have a trailing `,`

Comment: Thank you! String_AGG works. I did not know about that function.

Comment: The Type).value does not work because is still uses the ('''') to represent (''). For some reason we cannot use '' in the SQL string. I got the same error trying to use REPLACE with an '' empty string.

Comment: Maybe try escaping `'` like this `\'` instead of `''`